# Реализация анимации при межстраничном переходе

Tags: javascript

Как реализовать такой же переход между страницами без JQ? https://localmedia.ch/

Answer (score 0):

Нужно подгружать контент через *ajax* и менять адрес страниц через [pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/History/pushState).

Так же можно использовать готовые библиотеки, такие как [barba.js](https://barba.js.org).